# Does a JVM listen on an IPv6 debugging port?

Tags: debugging, jvm, ipv6

I cannot connect to a remote JVM on a host that only has an IPv6 interface.

What parameter should be passed to the JVM to enable listening on the IPv6 interface?

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately you can't. The Java VM being debugged only listens on IPv4. This is a known issue and is in [Oracle's documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jpda/conninv.html):

> The current implementation on the target VM side only supports IPv4, but this could change in a future release so that both IPv4 and IPv6 are supported.

One way to work around this would be to have a program (such as `xinetd` or `rinetd` for *nix-based servers) installed on the host, listening on IPv6, and forwarding connections to the IPv4 port that the JVM is listening on.

Comment: This sucks :( I spent entire day to debug the debugger issue and this seems to be the issue